# Spring MVC Path variable Case Sensitive Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

I have a Spring MVC Java web application. I have the following controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{service}/list", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResultData getList(@PathVariable String service,
        @RequestBody QueryData queryData, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //controller code
    return response;
}
```

And I have following in my **applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="some package" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="32771748" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

From the front end, I am trying to call the controller using AJAX call. The problem is Some URLs are working while the other gives **400 Bad Request** and **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect** error. I tried to connect using **RESTClient** in *Mozilla*.

If URL is

1. `/application/list` - Status is **200 OK**
2. `/business/list` - Status is **200 OK**
3. `/businessfunction/list` - Status is **200 OK**
4. `/businessFunction/list` - Status is **400 Bad Request**
5. `/tooltechnology/list` - Status is **400 Bad Request**
6. `/toolTechnology/list` - Status is **200 OK**

The first two are ok. But 3 and 4, one letter is in upper case in 4th, and it's not taking.
even if I try `businessfFunction`, it will work(added extra f before upper case letter F).

And in 5 and 6. I want to send like 5th case. ie, all are lower case and it's not working. But if I try with 6th, its working.

Why this is happening? And how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could exceptions happen in the controller code ?

Comment: It's not reaching in the controller. $00 Bad request says 'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect'. That's the problem. Problem while mapping to that controller because of the case. I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Do you have another controller mapped to URL /businnesFunction? If that's the case then, Spring will try to find /businessFunction/list inside that controller. In other words, make sure the {service} name does not conflict with any other request mapped URLs.

Comment: I don't have any. I have a URL  but that's just `/businnesFunction' and not `/businnesFunction/list`. So both are different right?

Comment: For `tooltechnology` I don't have any other mapping.